# Alternatives to solr

Tags: solr, lucene

We have 150GB solr db, and it's not terribly fast, even with a lot of hardware and optimization effort thrown at it.

Are any alternatives likely to be significantly faster?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer in its current form.

Answer (score 4):

We switched to elasticsearch and couldn't be happier. It still uses lucene but can horizontally scale better since it has build in sharding. So it should work well if you have multiple nodes for a 150gig DB.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Answer (score 0):

Well, changing search engine cannot make things fast by magic. To be fast your active indexes should fit in RAM.

I'd suggest you to re-view your indexing policy to reduce size and/or number of indexes in solr. Or if this is not possible - split indexes to multiple servers or get a server with enough RAM.